# Display Curl Response Sequential one by one

Tags: php, curl

I have simple POST CURL request script,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                                                              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem i am facing is, if i fetch post data from db or i fetch post data from a form, when i process data in large quantity, for example 60 times. The curl displays the output until and unless all 60 requests are completed.

I want the curl to display output one by one not all at once when the query is completed e.g.

Echo 1st Response
Echo 2nd Response
Echo 3rd Response

Comment: *"curl displays the output"* -- it doesn't display anything. You asked it to return the content of the response and this is what it does. And it cannot return until the entire data was received. You can, however, tell it to call a function you provide (a "callback") as soon as it receives blocks of data from the network. Investigate `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` on the documentation of the [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

What you are requesting appears to be undefined.

PHP, and any other HTTP Server can only start sending data, when the data-length is know. When `echo`ing, your server is supposed to assemble the reply, then organize a transfer.

If you want to assemble a document, that can be done, use AJAX, or any other request/reply system to assemble `div`s/fields each.

An example would be:

"`Base` document" -> [N] divs or fields. Each field requests its related procesing.
When `base`receives data, it assembles in its related div.